# Catch all exceptions in playframework and friendly error page in production

Tags: scala, playframework

Within my play application, I am logging as you would normally do within your code (trace, debug, error, etc).

For those errors that I don't catch, where can I put my logging so it caches an error that I missed?  Is there a central event that I can hook into that will catch all errors?

Also, how should I go about displaying a friendly error page whenever an error is thrown in my application?  (and how to have the error displayed in development, and the custom error page in production environment)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call default error pages in dev mode but not production (Play Framework 2.3.4 - Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378810/how-to-call-default-error-pages-in-dev-mode-but-not-production-play-framework-2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaGlobal#Providing-an-application-error-page

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  override def onError(request: RequestHeader, ex: Throwable) = {
    if (! Play.isProd) super.onError(request, ex)
    else 
      Future.successful(InternalServerError(
        views.html.errorPage(ex)
      ))
  }

}
```

Comment: how does play know if it is in prod or not?

Comment: `play run` is development mode.  Production mode can be started via `play start` or the methods outlined here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Production

Comment: OK now what is views.html.errorPage(ex)?  How do I create that?

Comment: OK let me try another way.  What does "views.html.errorPage(ex)" mean?  Is that a folder with a java class in it that contains a method errorPage() accepting an exception?  Or an HTML page called errorPage.html?  Or what?

Comment: @UpAllNight it is just a `Result` you can return Json object instead as in common action

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by extending the `GlobalSettings` trait, and overriding the `onError` method.

```
import play.api.GlobalSettings
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.mvc.Results._
import scala.concurrent.Future

object Global extends GlobalSettings {
    override def onError(request: RequestHeader, e: Throwable) = {
        Logger.error(e.getMessage)
        Future.successful(InternalServerError(views.html.defaultError()))
    }
}
```

Note that this `Global` object must be in the default package in order to work. `onError` is called whenever there is an unhandled exception within an `Action`. There, you'll have access to the original `Request`, and the exception that was thrown. Here, I'm just logging the exception message and returning a `Result` with some error view.